# How to display an array as a string, then put it through a query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, social-networking, feed

I am trying to take the users following post and display them with the users post as my news feed. I have the basic code set in place, however, when I ask to get the users in a comma separated list it displays as a array. For example, I printed the code and then it echoed 'Array,Array,user'. Is there any way for the array to actually display the user?

```
  <?php

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM follow WHERE follow_from='$user'";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

The while loop is where I believe I am having problems.

```
   while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false) {
    $following[] = array(
  'whofollow' => $row['follow_to'],

    );
   }


   if(!empty($following)) {
    array_push($following, $user);
  }else{
  $following = array($user);
  }
  $accepted_follow = implode("','", $following);
```

As you can see I tried to see what would print and it was 'Array,array,user' This user has two friends so I knew that it was the right about.

```
  print_r($accepted_follow);
```

Below is the post or the news feed itself. Below is where the user would see his or her post and also those who they follow.

```
            $get_photos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM   photos WHERE  username IN ('$accepted_follow') AND removed ='no' ORDER BY id DESC");
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($get_photos);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_photos)) {
              $id = $row['id'];
              $uid = $row['uid'];
              $username = $row['username'];  
              $date_posted = $row['date_posted'];  
              $description = $row['description']; 
              $image_url = $row['image_url']; 
              ?>
```

If there is any way where I could select the following post and the users post that would be very helpful!

```
  <?php

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM follow WHERE follow_from='$user'";

                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false) {
                $following = array('whofollow' => $row['follow_to'],);

            foreach ($following as $item) {
              if(is_array($item)){
                foreach ($item as $subItem) {
                   $printThis2[] = $subItem;
                }
              }else {
                  $following[] = $item;
              }
                 array_push($following, $user);

            $implodedString = implode(",",$following);

            }
               print_r($implodedString);

              }


            $get_photos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM   photos WHERE  username IN ('$accepted_follow') AND removed ='no' ORDER BY id DESC");
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($get_photos);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_photos)) {
              $id = $row['id'];
              $uid = $row['uid'];
              $username = $row['username'];  
              $date_posted = $row['date_posted'];  
              $description = $row['description']; 
              $image_url = $row['image_url']; 
              ?>
```

Comment: Was that 2 questions? To display the array, you could try `var_dump($accepted_follow)`.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not change it. The following users are still looked at as arrays @Huey

Answer (score 1):

It's printing

> Array, Array, user

because `$accepted_follow = implode("','", $following);` is only meant to be used when `$following` is a single one dimensional array, not when it's a multidimensional array containing what I assume is a `User` object.

A simple `var_dump` should confirm what `$following` actually contains, and then you can use a `foreach` loop or `implode` that alone to format it nicely.

For instance with this array:

```
$array = array(
    array("Pear","Mango"),
    array("Watermelon","Orange"),
    "Goat"
);
```

`var_dump($array)` will echo the following:

[image: d]

For the sample `$array` above, to print out all the items, I'd use:

```
$printThis = array()
foreach($array as $item){
    if(is_array($item)){
        foreach($item as $subItem){
             $printThis[] = $subItem; //since we know it's at most 2 dimensional. If we aren't sure how deep the array could be, a recursive function may be more useful.
        }
    } else{
        $printThis[] = $item;
    }
}
$implodedString = implode(",",$printThis);
```

and this should print

> Pear, Mango, Watermelon, Orange, Goat

Comment: That sounds pretty good! Thanks but what would the foreach loop look like? @huey

Comment: So what variable would I place into my sql? @huey

Comment: Also would I implode within the foreach loop or after? @huey

Comment: I'm confused. Is this still about printing out the array?

Comment: It prints out the users fine, $items is equal to useruser

Comment: usernameusername forexample 'princeking' prince and king two different users

Comment: wale','wale','osei
this was my last print out @huey

Comment: Problem is it doesnt give the right user, it duplicates one of the arrays @huey

Comment: You've changed your code and I have no idea what the issue is right now just from the fact `it duplicates one of the arrays`. Perhaps you could edit your question with these updates or post a new question (if this initial one is solved)?

Comment: Yeahh i found a fix to it thanks for all your time @huey